# There exists c such that $\int_0^1 x^2 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1/3 f(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that
$$\int_0^1 x^2 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac13f(c)$$

I am stuck with this one. $f$ is said to be continuous on $[a,b]$ so how can we conclude about $[0,1]$? Also can you please give me a clue about how to approach this problem? Integration by parts? Mean value theorem for integrals?

Comment: I think that $[a,b]$ should be $[0,1]$ or the exercise wouldn't make much sense. At least $[a,b]$ should be some interval containing $[0,1]$.

Comment: bound the integral by the maximum and minimum value of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ and then apply IVT.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mean value for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals), to conclude that there is $c \in (0,1)$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\, dx=f(c)\int_{0}^{1}g(x)\,dx$$ Let $g(x)=x^2$ in your case (which is a polynomial (hence integrable) and does not change sign on $(0,1)$).

Comment: I assumed that $[0,1] \subset [a,b]$. I don't know if I am allowed to do that...